# Error installing Homebrew onto macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Tags: homebrew

I've tried downloading brew with this link:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

However I'm getting the following error message:

```
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
HEAD is now at 771c961c5 Merge pull request #9001 from tie624/fix_url_missing_param
==> Tapping homebrew/core
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 20, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core` exited with 128.
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core` exited with 1.
Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to install it following the instructions on their website ? https://brew.sh/

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

best,